# Error en checkout de Spree gem, error "We are unable to calculate shipping rates for the selected items."

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

estoy empezando un ecommerce y uso Spree como gema

```
gem 'spree', '~> 3.2.0'
gem 'spree_auth_devise', '~> 3.2.0.beta'
gem 'spree_gateway', '~> 3.2.0.beta'
```

al querer hacer un pago obtengo esta alerta:

> We are unable to calculate shipping rates for the selected items.

me puse a investigar en google y segui varios consejos y nada! despues me tope con este blog: http://grokbase.com/t/gg/spree-user/164s4pctja/shipping-tax-categories-set-up-still-get-we-are-unable-to-calculate-shipping-rates-for-the-selected-items

segui los pasos que dice los cuales son

- Crear un Tax Category
- Crear Shipping Category
- Asociar las categorias de arriba con las del producto del carrito de compras

y en un mensaje al final del blog dice que tengo que hacer un "stock location"
el cual ya lo hize, pero sigo obteniendo ese error. algun consejo?

mis datos en el formulario checkout de Spree

```
Customer E-Mail 
prueba@gmail.com

Billing Address
First Name* 
joel

Last Name* 
garcia

Street Address* 
Yanga

Street Address (cont'd) 
Las palmas 14

City* 
Tuxpam

Country* Mexico

State* Veracruz

Zip* 
93250

Phone* 
7628716233
```

Answer (score 0):

Para que puedas avanzar al siguiente paso, asegurate de tener ingresadas las siguientes cosas:

- Zona de despacho
- Shipping Category
- Método de despacho (con la zona anterior y el shipping category)
- Producto debe tener el mismo shipping category
- Producto con stock o marcado como "backorderable"